# Same Function returning different results in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I run two queries and they are returning different results. Please help me find what am I missing.

```
select UPPER(TO_CHAR(Hire_date,'MONTH'))
from employees

returns a list of months(containing "2" entries for 'MARCH')

SELECT COUNT(EMPLOYEEID) "March Joinees"
FROM Employees
WHERE UPPER(TO_CHAR(Hire_date,'MONTH')) = 'MARCH';

returns 0 as count
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_char(<date>, 'Month')` produces a string of length equal to the greatest length of any month name (in the current session's language) - it does so by padding with spaces. This is why the second query produces no results; if you wrap the `upper....` within `trim(...)` it will work, but it would be better not to use `to_char(..., 'Month')` for this kind of query to begin with. I am sure you came to the same conclusion but you just want to know what is going on...

Here's an illustration. It may seem like the first column in the result is the string `'March'`; however, the second column doesn't lie: the result in the first column is actually `'March    '` (with four spaces at the end).

```
select to_char(date '2016-03-01', 'Month')           as month_as_string,
       length( to_char(date '2016-03-01', 'Month') ) as len
from   dual
;

MONTH_AS_STRING  LEN
---------------  ---
March              9
```

Then you may ask why Oracle made such a weird choice. That's a much tougher question. Anyway, this behavior is documented. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924 and scroll down to `MONTH` in table 2.15.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by mathguy already, `'MONTH'` makes padding with spaces. Try

```
SELECT '"'||TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'Month')||'"' FROM employees
```

to see the effect. Use either function [TRIM](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions235.htm#SQLRF06149) or Format Model Modifiers [FM](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#BABDAEDF)

Then result of `TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'Month')` depends your current session `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` value. Other session may get "März" or "Μάρτιος". Specify either date language or use Month numbers.

Actually `UPPER(TO_CHAR(Hire_date,'MONTH'))` is redundant. Format `MONTH` returns month name in upper case, you don't have to make `UPPER()` again.

Taking all this into account you should use one of the expressions below

```
WHERE TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'fmMONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = english') = 'MARCH'

WHERE UPPER(TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'fmMonth', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = english')) = 'MARCH'

WHERE TRIM(TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'MONTH', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = english')) = 'MARCH'

WHERE TO_CHAR(Hire_date, 'MM') = '03'

WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Hire_date) = 3
```

Comment: ... of which my recommendation by far (and I am sure yours as well) is just the last one!  :-)